# Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard": "2.3.7" will not resolve in .Net Core Project.json

Tags: active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I need to query ActiveDirectory to let the user pick names and add to the record they are saving.  I do not need to authenticate against AD, other then to set the connection to query against.

I stumbled across "Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard".

But when I try to pull it in it says "Package Restore Failed".  "The dependency Novell.Directory.Ldap.NetStandard >= 2.3.7 could not be resolved".

This is the line in my project.json:

```
"Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard": "2.3.7",
```

I see this person in this post trying to use it:

[C# netcore ldap authentication using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140051/c-sharp-netcore-ldap-authentication-using-novell-directory-ldap-netstandard-libr)

He is having trouble but at least it looks like it is trying to connect so he must have been able to install the dependency in project.json.

Anyone know how to get this dependency installed?
I really want to do it by hand in project.json.  The tooling really seems to hack up the files.
So I'm hesitant to use:

```
Install-Package Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard
```

in the package manager.

Here is my complete project.json so far:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
"Hrsa.Core.Generic.Model": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
//"Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard": "2.3.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc3",
"Hrsa.Core.Generic.Service": "1.0.0-*",
"Hrsa.Core.Generic.Repository": "1.0.0-*",
//"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel": "1.1.1",
//"AutoMapper": "6.0.2",
//"AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "2.0.1",
"Hrsa.Core.Common": "1.0.0-*"
```

},

```
  "tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

},

```
  "frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

},

```
  "buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
```

},

```
  "runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
```

},

```
  "publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "web.config",
  "Views",
  "appsettings.development.json",
  "appsettings.production.json",
  "appsettings.staging.json"
]
```

},

```
  "scripts": {
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and ran:

```
Install-Package Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard
```

It seemed to resolve.
Now I'll see if I can actually get it to work.